# After a random period of time, Windows is unable to see services running on my Linux subsystem and vice versa

Tags: linux, windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am running an Ubuntu 18.04 Linux Subsystem.

I have Postgresql 12 running on Linux, and I connect to this from my apps I am developing in Windows.

When I start up my PC, everything works fine.. DB can connect.

After an unspecified amount of time, half an hour, to a few days, Windows is no longer able to see Postgreql.  Connection to 127.0.0.1:5432 refused.

Restarting the Subsystem doesn't help. Restarting postgres doesn't help..

But the problem extends to other services and ports.. for example, if I have Apache running on Linux, when this issue arises, it is no longer able to do a proxy pass to my Windows services.

Not sure what else to try - I have the same setup on a different PC, and I don't have these problems.

It's almost as if a firewall comes up between the two systems, but it's more of a bug it seems.

Any suggestions welcomed!

Comment: Which version of Windows? Which build?

Comment: Windows 10 x64, Version 21H1 (OS Build 19043.928)